# Ошибка вычислений при запуске программы

Tags: python, рекурсия

Нужно создать алгоритм, который возвращает список - представление числа в виде непрерывной(цепной) дроби. Вот мой код:

```s
def piu(n):
    s.append(int(n))
    global q
    if len(s) == 1:
        q = n - int(n)
    else:
        q = 1 / q - int(1 / q)
    
    if n % 1 == 0:
        return s
    else:
        return piu(1 / q)

print(piu(2.515))
```

он должен вывести [2,1,1,16,6], но вместо этого выдает бесконечную рекурсию. добавив print(n) в начало функции, выдало:

```
2.515
1.9417475728155336
1.0618556701030932
16.16666666666655
6.000000000004178
       
239349469992.0544
18.37801458216489
2.645400593471809
1.5494252873563243
1.82008368200836
       ...
```

То есть, программа работает неправильно из-за погрешности вычислений питона.Как ее можно обойти,чтобы всё работало правильно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Алгоритм вычисления цепной дроби не использует вещественную арифметику. На вход подаётся пара *числитель/знаменатель* обыкновенной дроби. На выходе элементы цепной дроби:

```
def continued_fraction(n, d):
    while d != 0:
        yield n // d
        n, d = d, n % d


print(*continued_fraction(*map(int, input().split())))
```

> ```
> $ echo 2515 1000 | python continued-fraction.py
> 2 1 1 16 6
> ```

Если хочется работать с вещественным числом, то [float.as_integer_ratio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio). Получится, но кривовато:

```
def continued_fraction(n, d):
    while d != 0:
        yield n // d
        n, d = d, n % d


print(*continued_fraction(*float(input()).as_integer_ratio()))
```

> ```
> $ echo 2.515 | python continued-fraction.py
> 2 1 1 16 6 201053554793 6 4 2
> ```

Начало такое же, потом идёт огромное число *201053554793*. Это следствие того что десятичная дробь *2.515* не может быть записана точно в виде вещественного числа. А в виде [decimal.Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) может:

```
import decimal


def continued_fraction(n, d):
    while d != 0:
        yield n // d
        n, d = d, n % d


print(*continued_fraction(*decimal.Decimal(input()).as_integer_ratio()))
```

> ```
> $ echo 2.515 | python continued-fraction.py
> 2 1 1 16 6
> ```

И волки сыты и овцы целы.

Comment: Почему использование класса decimal предпочтительнее, чем использование функции round в данном случае?я попробовал с помощью round округлить значение n до 10 знака после запятой - всё сработало, как должно

Comment: 1. Потому что вам нужно знать как округлять. Это знание вы получили посмотрев конкретное число. У универсальной программы этой возможности нет. 2. Потому что когда вводится вещественное число происходит небольшая ошибка, которую исправляет `round`. Но этой ошибки нет вовсе при использовании `Decimal`. Зачем ломать и чинить, когда можно не ломать совсем?

Comment: `round` кстати ничего не исправляет. Вы им воспользовались, стало лучше. Теперь думайте как доказать что для всех чисел `round` сработает. Подсказка - не сработает.

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы всё работало правильно, нужно создать правильный алгоритм.
Дробь k/l
равна некоторой цепной дроби тогда и только тогда когда коэффициенты этой цепной дроби - последовательные неполные
частные в алгоритме Евклида для пары (k, l).

```
k = q1*l + r1,
l = q2*r1 + r2,
r1 = q3*r2 + r3,
r2 = q4*r3 + r4
```

Возьмем твое число 2.515, подсократим чуток дробь чтобы не маслать регистры процессора, получается 503/200
найдем  неполное частное с коэффциентами

```
503 = 2 * 200 + 103;
200 = 1 * 103 + 97;
103 = 1 * 97  + 6;
97  = 16* 6   + 1;
6   = 6 * 1   + 0;
```

[2,1,1,16,6]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Погрешность питона тут вообще ни каким боком.